# Slow Symfony2 application

Tags: php, symfony, optimization, curl, guzzle

There is a Symfony2 application based on API completely and makes 6 requests on average per page to API using [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle). Thus response time exceeds 3,000ms which is very high.

While investigating the slowness of the Symfony2 application on [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/), I realized that the slowest component is Guzzle by 90%.

```
Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti::executeHandles
```

Is it normal for Guzzle to become that slow? What to do in order to speed up the application?

Comment: it's probably nothing to do with guzzle but most likely network latency. i'd look into caching the api calls and fetching them in the backend every minute or so.

Comment: You could try sending the requests in parallel to try to cut down on the connection times. http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/http-client/client.html#sending-requests-in-parallel

Comment: These are good advices. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If your response does not depend on the data gained by guzzle's requests you could move these requests to the `kernel.terminate` event which is fired **after** the response has been sent to the client.

Read more about it [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-terminate-event).